# pkg_check_modules can't find different versions of same library

Tags: cmake, pkg-config

when using `pkg-config` in CMake through the `find_package(PkgConfig)` if I have multiple versions of the same library in different locations, the command stops at the first (wrong) one if I ask for a specific version, instead of searching along the other paths in the `$PKG_CONFIG_PATH` variable.

For instance, if my `$PKG_CONFIG_PATH` is `/opt/lib/pkgconfig:/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig` and I have Eigen 3.2.6 installed in `/opt/lib/pkgconfig` and Eigen 3.2.10 in `/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig`
then if I do:

`find_package(PkgConfig)
pkg_check_modules(EIGEN eigen3=3.2.10 REQUIRED)`

cmake stops with an error because it finds Eigen 3.2.6 first.

How to solve this?

Thanks.

Comment: If I correctly understand the [code](https://github.com/Kitware/CMake/blob/master/Modules/FindPkgConfig.cmake) of `pkg_check_modules`, it passes string `eigen3=3.2.10` directly to `pkg-config` tool. (More precisely, it splits string with spaces, `eigen3 = 3.2.10`). Have you tried to use your `pkg-config` tool with such argument?

Comment: @Tsyvarev: In this case it could be sufficient to pass it as "eigen3=3.2.10", don't it?

Comment: @Th.Thielemann: Not quite understand you. `it could be sufficient` - sufficient for **whom**? If CMake, it is just implemented as I have described above; I don't know whether this is correct or not. If you address that for the asker, he could try "eigen3=3.2.10", but "eigen3 = 3.2.10" may be tried as well.

Comment: Apparently, it is a limitation of pkg-config. I tried to run the command with different values of PKG_CONFIG_PATH. 

It just finds the first one in the list, no matter how version is installed.

I will try to write to the mailing list. It is strange that such an issue was not raised already.